# Error evaluating a TensorArray in a while loop

Tags: tensorflow

I've built the following `TensorArray`:

```
ta = tf.TensorArray(
    dtype=tf.float32,   
    size=0,
    dynamic_size=True,
    element_shape=tf.TensorShape([None, None])
)
```

and called `ta = ta.write(idx, my_tensor)` inside a `while_loop`.

When evaluating the `output = ta.stack()` tensor in a session, I receive this error message:

> ValueError: Cannot use '.../TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3' as
>   input to '.../TensorArrayStack_1/TensorArraySizeV3' because
>   '.../TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3' is in a while loop. See info
>   log for more details.

I don't understand this error message, could you please help me ?

Update: A minimal example might be difficult to come up with, but this is what I am doing: I am using the reference to the `ta` TensorArray inside the `cell_input_fn` of [AttentionWrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper). This callback is used in `AttentionWrapper`'s `call` method, where another `TensorArray` named `alignment_history` is being written. Therefore the `while_loop` code is not designed by me, it's part of the TF dynamic RNN computation `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

Comment: Hard to tell without any more code. Can you please post a full minimal example of the issue?

Comment: @jdehesa I updated my post a few hours ago, please let me now if this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what's biting you, but you have to make sure your while_loop function takes the tensor array as input and emits an updated one as output; and you have to use the *final* version of the TensorArray at the end of the while_loop:

```
def fn(ta_old):
  return ta_old.write(...)

ta_final = while_loop(..., body=fn, [tf.TensorArray(...)])

values = ta_final.stack()
```

specifically you should never access ta_old outside of fn().

Comment: The error gets triggered by the `size` call in `_GraphTensorArray`, which comes from `stack`. Since you know well the `AttentionWrapper` code, would it be possible to make `cell_input_fn` use the same RNN `while_loop` and update a `TensorArray` at the same time with the `alignment_history` `TensorArray` ?

Comment: Based on your comment, I think that I understand: the `while_loop` inside `dynamic_rnn` takes the cell state, an `AttentionWrapperState`, as one of the loop variables. Hence my `TensorArray` referenced in `cell_input_fn` does not get added to the loop vars. Would need a better design.